# Create update query based upon POST parameter

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a form which displays personal info of the person

```
   <form>
     <input type="text" name="per_name" id="name_1"/>
     <input type="text" name="per_mail" id="email_1"/>
     <input type="text" name="per_phone" id="phone_1"/>
   </form>
```

Now when i submit this form then an update query is called for databse like:

```
      if($_POST['name']!=['name from db']){
           $sql = "update table_1 set name=? where int_id=?";
      }
```

In this way i have to write three different update queries. But i want that the update query should be generated based on verifying if supplied values are different than already present values in DB.

Please guide here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well this could be done in one query using one update query:

```
$sql = "update table_1 set name=?, mail=?, phone=? where int_id=?";
```

3 diferent query are not required

and for validations, you can use

```
$name = $_POST['per_name'];
$mail = $_POST['per_mail'];
$phone = $_POST['per_phone'];
$qry = array();

if($name !== ['value from db'])
   $qry[] = 'name=?';

if($mail !== ['value from db'])
   $qry[] = 'mail=?';

if($phone !== ['value from db'])
   $qry[] = 'phone=?';

if(count($qry) > 0) {
   $qry = implode(', ', $qry);
   $updateQuery = "update table_1 set " . $qry . " where int_id=?";
   // Execute your query here
}
```

Comment: OP mentioned.. _update query should be generated **based on verifying** if supplied values are different than already present values in DB_

Comment: But i want to update only value that is different. I do not want to update same values again in Database

Comment: @GagandeepSharma, Modified my answer. Please have a look.

Comment: @ Marco Acierno .,, any suggestion? why this won't work

Comment: @MarcoAcierno, i respect your view here. If you could explain why this doesn't work. Maybe we could learn something that we do not know as yet

Comment: Oh sorry, but i don't get the notification. Anyway, nevermind my observation was wrong because i didn't think about the fact that the OP will change ['value from db'] with the correct code/data.

Answer (score 3):

One way you could solve this is to make a little change in your database.

Practically, *name* can be repeating but you cannot have the same *email address* used by 2 different people (*names*), so put a constraint of unique index for *email address* column.

Then, instead of update, use **[Replace INTO](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/replace.html)**:

```
$sql = "REPLACE INTO table_1 (name,email,phone) VALUES ({$_POST['per_name']},{$_POST['per_mail']},{$_POST['per_phone']})";
```

From the documentation:

> REPLACE works exactly like INSERT, except that if an old row in the
>   table has the same value as a new row for a PRIMARY KEY or a UNIQUE
>   index, the old row is deleted before the new row is inserted.

In the above case if the user is trying to enter the same e-mail ID, it will be *updated*, if it's a new e-mail ID, it will be *inserted*.

Comment: This is a better answer. Gagandeep Sharma should accept this as answer. +1 for using Replace Into Statement.

Comment: But @I Can Has Kittenz ... what if i have another values in table_1 (e.g Address) and i am not giving option to user to update those values.. and will `int_id` will also be changed by this?

Comment: @GagandeepSharma Depends on the attributes of `int_id`. If you're using the above method, then you would have to pass `int_id` somewhere in query (like in case if it's a user ID).